# php object : get value of attribute by computed name

Tags: php, object, get, attributes

How do I access an attribute of an object by name, if I compute the name at runtime?

For instance. I loop over keys and want to get each value of the attributes `"field_" . $key`.

In python there is `getattribute(myobject, attrname)`.

It works, of course, with `eval("$val=$myobject->".$myattr.";");`
but IMO this is ugly - is there a cleaner way to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Keep always in mind that a very powerful feature of PHP is its [Variable Variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

You can use

```
$attr = 'field' . $key;
$myobject->$attr;
```

or more concisely, using curl brackets

```
$myobject->{'field_'.$key};
```

Answer (score 8):

```
$myobject->{'field_'.$key}
```

Comment: +1 - you can use curly braces `{}` whenever you want PHP to evaluate their contents before the rest of the expression

Comment: Hello, Can I use something like this `$myObject->{'level1->level2'}`.. Or `$myObject->{level1}->{level2}`. How can I do it for multiple levels, when the level-values are dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

```
$val = $myobject->$myattr;
```

Answer (score 1):

With [reflection](http://it.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php):

```
$reflectedObject = new ReflectionObject($myobject);
$reflectedProperty = $reflectedObject->getProperty($attrName);
$value = $reflectedProperty->getValue($myobject);
```

This works only if the accessed property is public, if it's protected or private an exception will occurr.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old subject, but why not just use magic methods?

```
$myObj->__get($myAttr)
```