# Getting a variable from an object with a string in PHP

Tags: php, variables, object

I have a `Persons` object. It has a variable `name` accessible by saying

```
$p = new Person('John');
echo $p->name;
```

Now I have a string.

```
$name = 'name';
```

I need to get `$p->name` using `$p` and `$name`. Something like

```
echo $p->[$name];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [php object : get value of attribute by computed name ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537028/php-object-get-value-of-attribute-by-computed-name)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo $p->{$name};
```

Comment: Wow. That's easy. Why would the `{}` be necessary? I mean in what case would they be?

Comment: If you want to go all out with something like `$p->{functionA(functionB().$name)}` but it's a bit excessive ;) I also find it easier to read. `$p->$name` looks too much like `$p-$name`.

Answer (score 3):

echo $p->$name;

Answer (score 1):

> echo $p->$name;
>   may generates error if it contains special characters so following one is perfect

```
echo $p->{$name};
```